# Summing up columns of arrays of different shapes in array of arrays- Python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays, list, performance, numpy

I have an array that contains 2D arrays. 
For each 2D array i want to sum up the columns and the result must be in column form.
I have a piece of code to do this, but I feel like I am not utilising numpy optimally. What is the fastest to do this?
My current code:

```
temp = [np.sum(l_i,axis=1).reshape(-1,1) for l_i in self.layer_inputs]
```

Sample Array:

```
array([
    array([[  0.48517904, -11.10809746],
           [ 13.64104864,   5.77576326]]),
    array([[16.74109924, -3.28535518],
           [-4.00977275, -3.39593759],
           [ 5.9048581 , -1.65258805],
           [13.40762143, -1.61158724],
           [ 9.8634849 ,  8.02993728]]),
    array([[-7.61920427, -3.2314264 ],
           [-3.79142779, -2.44719713],
           [32.42085005,  4.79376209],
           [13.97676962, -1.19746096],
           [45.60100807, -3.01680368]]) 
], dtype=object)
```

Sample Expected Result:

```
[array([[-10.62291842],
       [ 19.41681191]]), 
 array([[13.45574406],
        [-7.40571034],
        [ 4.25227005],
        [11.7960342 ],
        [17.89342218]]), 
 array([[-10.85063067],
        [ -6.23862492],
        [ 37.21461214],
        [ 12.77930867],
        [ 42.58420439]])   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer

Given your stringent requirement for a list of arrays, there is no more computationally efficient solution.

#### Original answer

To leverage NumPy, don't work with a list of arrays: `dtype=object` is the hint you won't be able to use vectorised operations.

Instead, combine into one array, e.g. via `np.vstack`, and store split indices. If you need a list of arrays, use `np.split` as a final step. But this constant flipping between lists and a single array is expensive. Really, you should attempt to just store the splits and a single array, i.e. `idx` and `data` below.

```
idx = np.array(list(map(len, A))).cumsum()[:-1]  # [2, 7]
data = np.vstack(A).sum(1)
```

Comment: Oh actually i need the shape of (n,1) for some operations ill be performing on the array. About the code, it uses a lot of numpy functions and looks pretty time consuming given expescially since you;re converting the map object to list and then to a numpy array. Could you run a time test of my loop based code vs your current code? (Also it would be better if you could also arrange the result into shape (n,1) arrays)

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal, Nope, you can time it yourself :). The `map` bit is as efficient as you can get as your input is a list. I've updated my answer for your unusual shape.

Comment: Actually I tried the time test, but it takes -on an average- 3 to 4 times more time than my solution (even without the last line in your code which reshapes the array, it takes twice as much). I am looking for a solution which is be computationally efficient.

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal, Sure, see my update. If you choose to ignore the advice to avoid a list of arrays to begin with, there's little more I (or anyone else) can help.

Comment: What's the problem with list of arrays? Do you prefer an array of arrays instead? That's fine by me.

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal, No, the only vectorisable solution is **one, just one, homogeneous array**. I've tried to illustrate that in my answer. Don't use a list of arrays, don't use an array of arrays.

Comment: One array is not the kind of problem the question asks for. If the result you have in mind is for one single array then it is not relevant to the question at all anyway.

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal, My solution with `idx` + `data` is lossless, i.e. you can reconstruct your inefficient [list of arrays, or array of arrays] result if desired. A more efficient lossless solution is entirely in-scope.